Unable to Upgrade Drupal Core to 10.2.4 (Security Update)
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upgrade my Drupal core installation to version 10.2.4, which includes important security updates. Despite following the usual update procedures, I'm unable to complete the upgrade successfully.
Here are the details of my problem:
I've attempted to upgrade my Drupal core installation to version 10.2.4 using the recommended update process.
Tried these
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:10.2.4 "install-dir"

composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies

composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.2.4 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.2.4 drupal/core-project-message:10.2.4 --update-with-all-dependencies

error:
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drush/drush ^9, found drush/drush[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires drupal/core-dev ^10, found drupal/core-dev[10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.3.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 9.5.9 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
 Problem 3
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.x-dev requires drupal/core 10.0.x-dev -> found drupal/core[10.0.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.x-dev requires drupal/core 10.1.x-dev -> found drupal/core[10.1.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.x-dev requires drupal/core 10.2.x-dev -> found drupal/core[10.2.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

My composer.json
{
    "name": "drupalcommerce/project-base",
    "description": "Commerce 2.x project template",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "commerce_base": {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base"
        },
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "slick": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "library-kenwheeler/slick",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://git@github.com/kenwheeler/slick.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "1.6.0"
                },
                "require": { "composer/installers": "~1.0" }
            }
        },
        "oauth2-server": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server.git"
        }
    },
    "config": {
      "bin-dir": "bin",
      "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "commerceguys/addressing": "^1.4.2",
        "commerceguys/intl": "^1.1",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal/address": "^1.11",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.23",
        "drupal/block_class": "^2.0",
        "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.31",
        "drupal/commerce_cart_api": "^1.7",
        "drupal/components": "^3",
        "drupal/config_filter": "^1.12",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^3.2",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.9",
        "drupal/console": "~1.9",
        "drupal/consumers": "^1.17",
        "drupal/contact_block": "^1.7",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.13",
        "drupal/date_popup": "^1.3",
        "drupal/devel": "^5.1",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.4",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.11",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.4",
        "drupal/file_entity": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.1",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/key": "^1.17",
        "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.4",
        "drupal/maxlength": "^2.1",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.3",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^4.1",
        "drupal/neato": "^2.0",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.17",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.12",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.10",
        "drupal/queue_ui": "^3.1",
        "drupal/recommended-project": "^10",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.9",
        "drupal/rest_export_nested": "^1.2",
        "drupal/restui": "^1.21",
        "drupal/s3fs": "^3.4",
        "drupal/search_api": "~1.0",
        "drupal/seckit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.10",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.8",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.2",
        "drupal/stage_file_proxy": "^1.5",
        "drupal/state_machine": "^1.11",
        "drupal/swiftmailer": "^2.4",
        "drupal/token": "^1.13",
        "drupal/tokenuuid": "^2.0",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.3",
        "drupal/username_enumeration_prevention": "^1.3",
        "drupal/views_extras": "^3.0",
        "drupalcommerce/commerce_base": "dev-8.x-1.x",
        "drush/drush": "^9",
        "library-kenwheeler/slick": "dev-master",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
        "vinceg/usps-php-api": "^1.0",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^10"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset",
                "type:drupal-console-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ]
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/commerce_cart_api": {
                "cart-api-clear-cart": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-08-30/2974429-3.patch"
            },
            "drupal/field_encrypt": {
                "commerce-breaks-settings-page": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/field_encrypt-2897256-2-commerce.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}


Why do you require drush/drush in v9? The last update from that version was published three years ago

You should try to change the drush restraint to at least "drush/drush": "^12". See if that eliminates the error. Seems like that's what the error is indicating.
